# Let $\phi:c_0\to\mathbb{K}$ given by $\phi\left((a_j)_{j=1}^\infty\right)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{a_j}{2^j}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, operator-theory

In this exercise $$c_0:=\{(\xi_j)_{j=1}^\infty\subset\mathbb{K} : (\xi_j)_{j=1}^\infty\hspace{.1cm}\mbox{ converges to zero}\},$$
and $\mathbb{K}$ it represents $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

***The goal is to show that there is no $x\in c_0$ such that $\|x\|\leq 1$ and $\|\phi\|=|\phi(x)|.$***

Let us reason by contradiction, that is, suppose that there exists $x\in c_0$ such that $\|x\|\leq 1$ y $\|\phi\|=|\phi(x)|.$

It is not difficult to show that $\phi$ is well defined and that $\|\phi\|=1$, with this I have not had a problem. Now, $$1=\|\phi\|=|\phi(x)|=\left|\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{a_j}{2^j}\right|\leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left|\frac{a_j}{2^j}\right|\leq \|x\|\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j}=\|x\|\leq 1.$$

So $\|x\|=1$. Here is the detail, I do not see how to get to contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that there is a place in your last expression where you can place a strict inequality, because the sequence $x$ goes to zero.